# Magento 1.9.3.2 Transactional Email style

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail, inline-translations

I have updated Magento from 1.9.3.2 to 1.9.3.6. But after updating to this latest version, Magento is ignoring **email-inline.css** file for Transactional email. Because all the **sales emails** templates were working fine before updating but now system is not applying **emial-online.css** styles. 
But when I write css directly in template in Magento Admin panel, than system apply those css styles.

I have already checked my settings in Admin -> configuration -> General  -> Design -> Transactional Email  (Non-inline CSS File) field.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**
 I was using **composer's symlink deploy** strategy for Magento install. But Magento has discard the symlink property after 1.9.3.2. 
So as I updated to 1.9.3.6, so system was not able to fetch *email-inline.css* file, which is used for styling the transactional email.
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Abstract.php (_getCssContent) method has been updated in post version of 1.9.3.2 
`$filePath = realpath($filePath);` this fetch file's path from **vendor** folder.
`$positionSkinDirectory = strpos($filePath, Mage::getBaseDir('skin'));` "Mage::getBaseDir('skin')" fetch path from **public** folder 
So in results, `$positionSkinDirectory = flase` 
So logic will not go into `if` condition later in the method and it returns empty string.
**Solution:** Please update your composer
"extra": {
    "magento-root-dir": "public",
    "magento-deploystrategy": "copy"
  },
composer reference link: https://github.com/Cotya/magento-composer-installer